# Slim Framework - How to query db in normal function

Tags: php, api, slim

I'm very new to PHP and Slim Framework which helps creating APIs. 
Everything is ok If i query db inside `$app->post` or `get`. But I want to separate it to normal function. It will help when I need to use it later in other APIs.

I tried to call this

```
$app->get('/search/[{phone}]', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app){
    $token = $response->getHeader('token');
    // $phone = $args['phone'];
    if (isTokenValid($token)){
        return $this->response->withJson("valid");
    }
    return $this->response->withJson("invalid");

});
```

My `isTokenValid()` function

```
function isTokenValid($token){
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE token = :token';
    $s = $app->db->prepare($sql); //<< this line 25
    $s->bindParam(':token', $token);
    if ($s->execute()){
        if($sth->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I get `500 Internal Server Error`

```
Type: Error
Message: Call to a member function prepare() on null
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aigoido/src/functions.php
Line: 25
```

How to call it outside `$app`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a dependency injection container for your database connection and pass that object in as the function parameter rather than app object.  This makes the db connection reusable throughout your app.

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/di.html

Also, you can return $response rather than $this->response.

```
$c = $app->getContainer();

$c['db'] = function() {
    return new DB($host,$user,$pass,$name);
};

$app->post('/search/[{phone}]', function($request, $response, $args) use ($c) {
     $token = $response->getHeader('token');
    // $phone = $args['phone'];
    if (isTokenValid($c->db,$token)){
        return $response->withJson("valid");
    }
    return $response->withJson("invalid");    
});


function isTokenValid($db, $token){
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE token = :token';
    $s = $db->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindParam(':token', $token);
    if ($s->execute()){
        if($sth->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$app` to your function as parameter. The function has it own context so $app is not available without that.

```
function isTokenValid($token, $app){
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE token = :token';
    $s = $app->db->prepare($sql); //<< this line 25
    $s->bindParam(':token', $token);
    if ($s->execute()){
        if($sth->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I edited to what you told, but i have new error `Call to a member function prepare() on null`. Thanks.

Comment: @TruongHieu did u add the parameter inside the function call?

Comment: In order to call `$app->db->prepare` you need to add `db` to `$app`'s container first. Check Rob's answer above.